# Why does Firefox suddenly give a Session Timeout error when attempting to access an Oracle Apex app?

Tags: firefox, oracle-apex

My PC is on a Windows 10 64-bit platform and have a 4 browsers loaded.  My preferred browser is Firefox Quantum 69.0 (64-bit).  Starting today, when I log into an Oracle Apex application I get the error "Your session has expired" on the Apex logon page.  When I use Chrome Version 77.0.3865.75 the application works perfectly.   When I use Internet Explorer 11.356.18362.0 it works fine as well.
The server is configured with Oracle Apex 19.1 and Apache 2.4, but nothing has changed on the server.
Any idea why Firefox would suddenly produce this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but this happened to me this week also.  In the end I deleted all my stored cookies and then APEX started working properly again.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  I removed cookies just for the server's site and it fixed the problem.  In Firefox I used 1) Menu bars, 2) Options cog, 3) Privacy & Security padlock 4) Cookies and Site Data / Manage Data.  Thanks again for all your help.